# Flexbasis vs padding in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

Assuming I have two separate components with the following properties :

- flex: 1, paddingTop: 30
- flex: 1, flexBasis: 30

Is there any difference? It seems like regardless of the padding type used the child component will still render at the "start" of the parent component (or as early as it is allowed to be rendered).

When designing layouts, when would you use padding over flexBasis? Is it simply a guideline that when using flex it's best to also use flexBasis (over padding)?

Comment: Padding and basis are not interchangeable. Basis and width are interchangeable when flexDirection is row. And basis and height are interchangeable when flexDirection is column.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the above examples with flexDirection : column in mind. In that case, paddingVertical and flexBasis would be interchangeable?

Comment: Also my mistake, earlier I said "width"/"height" but its really minWidth/minHeight. flexBasis is not interchangable with padding, all though paddingVertical will grow in the same direction. flexBasis has a lot of other effects you can read about here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax